# Функция суффиксов

Tags: суффиксы, морфемика

Ножка - суффикс К - формообразующий. 
По-новому - суффикс ОМУ - словообразующий.
Слева - суффикс А - формообразующий.
Соизмерять - суффикс Я - словообразующий, Ø - формообразующий.
Разрезать - суффикс А - словообразующий, ть - формообразующий.
Помогать - суффикс А - словообразующий, ть- формообразующий.
Сказать - суффикс А - словообразующий, ть- формообразующий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ножка - суффикс К - словообразующий.

Слева - суффикс А - словообразующий.

Соизмерять - суффикс Я - словообразующий, ть - формообразующий.